# Laravel paginate() method doesn't work in index controller method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-5.4

I am a newbie to Laravel development. I have checked the documentation of Laravel for using database pagination. I found that I can use paginate(numbreOfLines) to paginate.

Whenever I write in my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $users= User::paginate(3);
    }
```

It doesn't work. I don't know why. I am using Laravel 5.4

Comment: Please dd($users) and show result set of $users

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: What is error message explain your exact issue.

Comment: You need to elaborate your question. Its not enough to drop this here with little to no information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have defined table name in Model User.php file

```
  public function index()
  {
    $users= User::paginate(3);
    return $users;
  }
```

Comment: return view('page',['user' => $users]); if you need to return to view

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the results to the view , that's why you get nothing.

```
public function index()
{
    $users= User::paginate(3);
     return view('view.blade.php')->with('users', $users);
}
```